# How does a database read data change during the transaction?

Tags: sql, database, transactions

Let's assume the following scenario:

```
[Start TX]
SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userId = 1; -- returns x
UPDATE users SET userName = 'y' where userId = 1;
SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userId = 1; -- returns y
[End TX]
```

How does the database knows to return y the second time? How is the transaction state integrated into the query processing?

Another scenario:

```
[Start TX]
SELECT userName FROM users, accounts WHERE useres.userId = accounts.userId AND accounts.balance < 0; -- returns x
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 100 where userId = 1;
SELECT userName FROM users, accounts WHERE useres.userId = accounts.userId AND accounts.balance < 0; -- returns nothing
[End TX]
```

Same question - how does the database runs the join over the transaction information?

Comment: I voted to close this question, not because it is not a good question, but it is way too general.  Each database is going to approach this in its own way.  It is possible that this question is more appropriate for the DBA forum.  However, you should look at the documentation for the database you are interestedin.

Comment: This depends heavily on the DBMS being used. The strategy used by SQL Server is totally different to that of Oracle or PostgreSQL. See e.g. here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's think on database table as [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). Let me talk couple words on it datastructure - all we should know for your topic that B-tree is page organized. Assume you have 9 rows (marked from `A..I`) and B-tree with page size=3. Some way we have 3 pages on disk

```
Page1: A,B,C,
Page2: D,E,F
Page3: G,H,I
```

Assume you have changed something in row `E`. Your database **connection** will allocate memory for the page2 and totally load it (`D..F`). You made changes to `E` but transaction is not committed. Now you try to select (in the same **connection**). Since memory is already contains page loaded, your SELECT will see data that is modified. 
But if **another connection** will try load `E` it have to load to memory in-mutable `D..F` page2. After commit page2 is persisted, so all another **connections** could see changes.

Of course in real world the process much more complicated.

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for.
So the database basically keep a copy of changed blocks, in memory, for each transaction (I assume there's some kind of swapping mechanism for long running transactions). Then when it needs to consult a block, it first goes to the connection private storage and only if it didn't find the block there, it goes to the shared storage.
Does this apply for indexes as well?

Comment: @RanBiron once again description above is very primitive. This primitive describe how most simple isolation level implementation works. Transaction is tightly coupled to this, but also introduce some another storage - journaling of trsnasaction, that answers how to grant that page2 is fully stored in consistent way. About indexes - most indexes in db are based on B-Tree, so changes in indexes have to be placed to 'private storage' as well

Comment: Thanks. Is there a name for this behavior? Something I can use to further drill in to?
Also, I'm marking this as accepted - it's the information I was looking for (I'll remove the 2nd question and ask it independently).

Comment: @RanBiron what the name you ask for? Main concetion of paging called clustered index - how records are ordered in physical order

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading the following article:

[SQL Server 2005 Row Versioning-Based Transaction Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345124%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

While the article is specifically about Sql Server 2005, it gives a great summary of the various types of concurrency control:

> There are two primary models that are used in controlling concurrency:
>   pessimistic concurrency and optimistic concurrency.
>
> In a pessimistic concurrency control-based system, locks are used to
>   prevent users from modifying data in a way that affects other users.
>   After a lock has been applied, other users cannot perform actions that
>   would conflict with the lock until the owner releases it. This level
>   of control is used in environments where there is high contention for
>   data, and where the cost of protecting the data by using locks is less
>   than the cost of rolling back transactions if or when concurrency
>   conflicts occur.
>
> Conversely, in an optimistic concurrency control-based system, users
>   do not lock data when they read it. When an update is performed, the
>   system checks to see whether another user has changed the data after
>   it was read. If another user updated the data, an error is raised.
>   Typically, the user that receives the error rolls back the
>   transaction, and then resubmits the transaction. This is called
>   optimistic concurrency because it is mainly used in environments where
>   there is low contention for data, and where the cost of occasionally
>   rolling back a transaction outweighs the costs of locking data when it
>   is read.
>
> Read committed isolation using row versioning is somewhere in between
>   pessimistic and optimistic concurrency. Under this isolation level,
>   read operations do not acquire locks against the live data. However,
>   with update operations the process is the same for this isolation
>   level as it is for the default read committed isolation level: The
>   selection of rows to update is done by using a blocking scan where an
>   update lock is taken on the data row as data values are read.
>
> Snapshot isolation, on the other hand, is truly optimistic because
>   data that is to be modified is not actually locked in advance, but the
>   data is locked when it is selected for modification. When a data row
>   meets the update criteria, the snapshot transaction verifies that the
>   data has not been modified by another transaction after the snapshot
>   transaction started. If the data has not been modified by another
>   transaction, the snapshot transaction locks the data, updates the
>   data, releases the lock, and moves on. If the data has been modified
>   by another transaction, an update conflict occurs and the snapshot
>   transaction rolls back.

Like the comments suggested, the type of concurrency control used varies not only by the database platform being used, but also varies within platforms based on the settings used.

Answer (score 0):

You can have access to dirty data from the same transaction for any transaction isolation level.

Comment: yes, but how exactly is this done? At the end of the process, the query processor goes to a specific cache (or cause a data block to be loaded into cache) and perform a hash-scan/range-scan/row access. How does the processor knows that a specific row has been overridden by the transaction "dirty data" - especially for range-scans/hash-scans?

Comment: In a nutshell, when you try to change data, engine first set kind of lock depended on what you need, if success it change data. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx for mode info.